# Linderdaum engine demos for Android - missing files

Tags: android, c++, ant, linderdaum

I am building Linderdaum Engine demos for Android and it fails on missing reference to CommonMedia.XML. I have downloaded the official SDK 0.6.08 but there is no such file there. How can I generate that file?

Comment: is that .jar file? did you put that in libs folder?

Comment: It is open source. All java files are there. Seems to be a problem while building .apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommonMedia.xml contains targets to copy common data files from SDK's folder into your apk. This file is missing in the official SDK release 0.6.08. You can grab the recent CommonMedia.xml from here http://www.linderdaum.com/temp/CommonMedia.xml It should be placed in BuildAndroid folder.